# How to copy record to another table with its relationship using LINQ and EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

I need to copy alert details to Case details with its relation of customer, accounts etc. which is of related to alert as one alert to many customer. I tried this way but it gives me an error 
*"The EntityCollection has already been initialized. The InitializeRelatedCollection method should only be called to initialize a new EntityCollection during deserialization of an object graph."*

```
 if (alertDetails.IncidentAccounts != null)
            caseDetails.IncidentAccounts = alertDetails.IncidentAccounts;
        if (alertDetails.IncidentCustomers != null)
            caseDetails.IncidentCustomers = alertDetails.IncidentCustomers;
        if (alertDetails.IncidentTransactions != null)
            caseDetails.IncidentTransactions = alertDetails.IncidentTransactions;
        if (alertDetails.IncidentCheckFraudTransactions != null)
            caseDetails.IncidentCheckFraudTransactions = alertDetails.IncidentCheckFraudTransactions;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of those objects are collections you need to copy them accordingly:

`caseDetails.IncidentAccounts.AddRange( alerdDetails.IncidentAccounts )`

but it is really hard to tell without seeing the model definition.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
but there is no method for EntityCollection<Entity> dosen't have method AddRange();

Comment: it is really hard to know for me here without seeing the actual model definition for caseDetails and alertDetails object respectively...